# How to preserve formatting of google spreadsheet in mail merge?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to send an email with google spreadsheet content as a body with formatting. I took the reference from [here](https://www.labnol.org/send-rich-text-emails-200830) but it's only working with cell 'A1' and I want it to work with the complete data range. How to preserve all the formatting while sending the email?

[image]

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].  The only way to get the formatting in the email is by sending html email but of course that won't preserve the formating.  You would have to recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `getRichTextValues` to get all the rich text values of each cell in the range given and then iterate each of them. Then compile them and format into a table.

Also, since the script didn't include the background, I have added it as well. See working script, sample data and the output below.

#### Script Modification:

```
const sendRichEmail = () => {
  // update cellAddress if needed, or use getDataRange below instead.
  const cellAddress = 'A1:B2';
  const sheetName = 'Mail Merge';
  const recipient = 'test@email.com';

  const richTextValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getRange(cellAddress)
    .getRichTextValues();

  // Adding background color
  const backgroundColors = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getRange(cellAddress)
    .getBackgrounds();

  /* Run is a stylized text string used to represent cell text.
     This function transforms the run into HTML with CSS
   */
  const getRunAsHtml = (richTextRun) => {
    const richText = richTextRun.getText();

    // Returns the rendered style of text in a cell.
    const style = richTextRun.getTextStyle();

    // Returns the link URL, or null if there is no link
    // or if there are multiple different links.
    const url = richTextRun.getLinkUrl();

    const styles = {
      color: style.getForegroundColor(),
      'font-family': style.getFontFamily(),
      'font-size': `${style.getFontSize()}pt`,
      'font-weight': style.isBold() ? 'bold' : '',
      'font-style': style.isItalic() ? 'italic' : '',
      'text-decoration': style.isUnderline() ? 'underline' : '',
    };

    // Gets whether or not the cell has strike-through.
    if (style.isStrikethrough()) {
      styles['text-decoration'] = `${styles['text-decoration']} line-through`;
    }

    const css = Object.keys(styles)
      .filter((attr) => styles[attr])
      .map((attr) => [attr, styles[attr]].join(':'))
      .join(';');

    const styledText = `<span style='${css}'>${richText}</span>`;
    return url ? `<a href='${url}'>${styledText}</a>` : styledText;
  };

  // Format the data that will work on multiple cells. 
  // Edit table properties if needed
  var finalBody = `<html><body><table border='1px'>`;
  /* Returns the Rich Text string split into an array of runs,
  wherein each run is the longest possible
  substring having a consistent text style. */
  for (var i = 0; i < richTextValue.length; i++) {
    finalBody += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < richTextValue[i].length; j++) {
      finalBody += `<td bgcolor='${backgroundColors[i][j]}'>`;
      finalBody += richTextValue[i][j].getRuns().map((run) => getRunAsHtml(run)).join('');
      finalBody += '</td>';
    }
    finalBody += '</tr>';
  }
  finalBody += '</table></body></html>';

  MailApp.sendEmail({to: recipient, subject: 'Rich HTML Email', htmlBody: finalBody});
};
```

#### Sample Data:

[image: sample]

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- I have also formatted it to have the data sent as table instead. Feel free to modify the properties of the table if needed.
- To reduce the spacing between cells, use this:

#### Cellspacing 0:

```
var finalBody = `<html><body><table border='1' cellspacing='0'>`;
```

#### Output:

[image: output2]

#### Reference:

- https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_padding_spacing.asp

#### EDIT:

- It is a limitation of `getRichTextValues` for both date objects and numbers. Alternatively, you can use `getDisplayValues` to insert those values but won't have the proper text styles due to `getTextStyles` returning nothing.

[image: issue]

#### Modified Script:

```
const sendRichEmail = () => {
  const sheetName = 'Sheet1';
  const recipient = 'test@email.com';

  const richTextValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getDataRange()
    .getRichTextValues();

  // get string equivalent of the data
  const values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getDataRange()
    .getDisplayValues();

  const backgroundColors = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    .getSheetByName(sheetName)
    .getDataRange()
    .getBackgrounds();

  // pass the current index of row and column
  const getRunAsHtml = (richTextRun, i, j) => {
    var richText = richTextRun.getText();
    // if richText is empty, assign value from getDisplayValues
    if (!richText)
      richText = values[i][j];
    const style = richTextRun.getTextStyle();
    const url = richTextRun.getLinkUrl();

    const styles = {
      color: style.getForegroundColor(),
      'font-family': style.getFontFamily(),
      'font-size': `${style.getFontSize()}pt`,
      'font-weight': style.isBold() ? 'bold' : '',
      'font-style': style.isItalic() ? 'italic' : '',
      'text-decoration': style.isUnderline() ? 'underline' : '',
    };

    if (style.isStrikethrough()) {
      styles['text-decoration'] = `${styles['text-decoration']} line-through`;
    }

    const css = Object.keys(styles)
      .filter((attr) => styles[attr])
      .map((attr) => [attr, styles[attr]].join(':'))
      .join(';');

    const styledText = `<span style='${css}'>${richText}</span>`;
    return url ? `<a href='${url}'>${styledText}</a>` : styledText;
  };

  var finalBody = `<html><body><table border='1px'>`;
  for (var i = 0; i < richTextValue.length; i++) {
    finalBody += '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; j < richTextValue[i].length; j++) {
      finalBody += `<td bgcolor='${backgroundColors[i][j]}'>`;
      // pass i and j into getRunAsHtml
      finalBody += richTextValue[i][j].getRuns().map((run) => getRunAsHtml(run, i, j)).join('');
      finalBody = finalBody.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
      finalBody += '</td>';
    }
    finalBody += '</tr>';
  }
  finalBody += '</table></body></html>';


  MailApp.sendEmail({ to: recipient, subject: 'Rich HTML Email', htmlBody: finalBody });
};
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Hi. First of all thanks for the help. Your modified code are work pretty well, but the only issue with the script is not capturing the numeric values of the Spreadsheet. For reference, see the attached [sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EIBkBFta6ZycwC2UMWNTaYFQ7cdqz2KfyKKhMh_6RB0/edit#gid=1089100420).

Comment: Hi @SumitSingh, sadly, that is a current limitation of richtextvalues. They do not return date objects and numbers. See [related post and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67715023/i-cant-get-text-from-richtextvalue). However, you can use `getDisplayValues` to get those values. The catch is it wont get the text style since nothing was returned by `getTextStyle`. I'll update the answer shortly to include those cells with date/numbers.

Comment: I have now updated the answer and you should see the **EDIT** section at the bottom. @SumitSingh

Comment: Hi @Octavia Sima, thanks for the help. I have modified the code a little bit to format numbers into text and now it's working as expected.

Comment: Hi @SumitSingh, If this answered your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Hi @Octavia Sima, Can we get the merge cells formatting too? I mean what if we merge 2 cells and want to pick them as it is in the email with formatting, is it possible?

Comment: @SumitSingh, I think you would need colspan and rowspan for that in your formatting. But i'd recommend you post another question for it so that other people will see your question too and might be able to provide you a more specific answer.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately, currently I am restricted to posting a new question, so will you please help me here. I need it. All I need to pick merged rows and columns in the email.

Comment: Hi @SumitSingh, [Let's try to be focused on out future posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266768/17842569). I don't see any restrictions on your account so you should be able to post a question. And if you are not able to do so, feel free to ask a new question on a new account.