# sheet.range().getRichTextValue() returns null even though it is correctly set

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm having a problem with rich text values in spreadsheets. The following code sets the rich text value (a URL) in a cell but getting the rich text value returns null. It appears that the problem is related to the fact that the rich text value text is numeric.

```
function SheetEdit(e) {
  let sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  let row = e.range.getRow();
  let col = e.range.getColumn();
  let year = 2022;
  // The following getRichTextValue() returns correctly. Its text value is non-numeric.
  let folderId = sheet.getRange(row,1).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl().split('/')[5];
  let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  let filelist = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);
  if (filelist.hasNext()==true) {
    let file = filelist.next();
    let url = file.getUrl().split('?')[0]; // remove URL parameters
    // The following setRichTextValue() correctly sets the value in the spreadsheet.
    // Its text value (year) is numeric.
    let richText = SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(String(year)).setLinkUrl(url).build();
    sheet.getRange(row,col).setRichTextValue(richText);
    // However, the following getRichTextValue() returns null
    Logger.log(sheet.getRange(row,col).getRichTextValue().getText());
    Logger.log(sheet.getRange(row,col).getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl());
  }
}
```

Comment: I thought that your question is related to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67715023/7108653). In your expected goal, what result do you want to obtain?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that it was a known issue.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/158393310).  One way to work around it is to change

```
SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText(String(year))
```

to

```
SpreadsheetApp.newRichTextValue().setText("'"+year)
```

This will cause the year (number) to be interpreted/displayed by the spreadsheet as text (without the leading `'`) rather than as a number.  When you call

```
sheet.getRange(row,col).getRichTextValue().getText()
```

you'll get `2022` as expected.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize that it was a known issue. Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: @TaiJin I didn't realize it either until I read the link from Tanaike. I'm glad you pointed it out.